# What is the benefits of "Declare @TableName" over "Create Table TableName"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, sqlperformance

A performance-enhancement task is assigned to me, at work.
We are running SQL Server 2012. The DB has many tables with millions of rows and the report takes more than 30 mins to view results.

Running the Stored Proc with including the execution plan showed that about 98% is consumed during "Declare @T Table" and inserting and selecting from it. After a couple of hours of trials and errors, I changed this part into "Create Table T" and dropped the created table at the end of the Proc.

The result is charming. Now it takes less than 10 mins to retrieve the data.
Any one can explain me the reasons why this happens?

I don't know if I need to continue with this method or there is some thing else I have to take care about.

Answer (score 1):

The percentages are just estimates, which are based on row count estimates -- and that can be your problem. Table variables do not have statistics, so in most cases SQL Server estimates that there is 1 row in the table.

If you're using those table variables in joins or anything like that, the query plan might be really bad because of the wrong estimation on the number of rows.

If there's no reason to use table variables, you should first try to use normal temp. tables (#tableName). If you have a lot of rows in those tables, creating index(es) might be a good idea too.

Comparing the query plan, estimates for number of rows and statistics io output should give you a rough idea what is the difference between the executions. Don't trust the percentages that much, those can be totally wrong, but statistics io can be trusted (unless, you're using multi statement UDFs there too)